# User privacy and using arrays that store user Ids

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This just dawned on me recently, what if I have the following schema:

```
Posts: {
    ...
    flaggedByUsers: [],
    flagCount: 
}
```

...where flaggedByUsers store user _ids and flagCount stored a total count of users flagging the post.

Since I need to publish part of Meteor.user for the profile object of all users (is this a good idea?), I noticed that since the user _id is always visible because of this, and flaggedByUsers is used to determine whether to hide the content from users who flagged it, as another user, I'll be able to see who flagged the post through the console.

I'm deliberating whether this is a big deal or not (as in the case of Reddit, you can't see who up/down voted). Any suggestions to how to hide the _ids? I was thinking of using another field that has a randomly generated value like _id and visible only to the logged in user, then use the value from that field to insert into flaggedByUsers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publishing profile data for other users is unlikely to be a problem unless the profiles contain sensitive data. Your concerns about the `flaggedByUsers` field make sense, though going to great lengths to conceal the information from the console seems like a premature measure (how many people are really going to find this immediately after your service goes live?).

Given the constraints:

- Users should not see `flaggedByUsers` data.
- Users should not see posts which they have flagged.

Perhaps you could implement your posts publish like this:

```js
Meteor.publish('posts', function() {
  return Posts.find(
    {flaggedByUsers: {$ne: this.userId}}, {fields: {flaggedByUsers: 0}}
  );
});
```

Comment: Hmm point taken. What I did rather, was show everything and whenever there a post or comment was flagged, it will compare it what the logged in user's tolerance for flags, and if it meets the condition, hide flagged content and show a button to show/hide the content. I'll take a closer look at the find() condition you shared